# Updating a database field when Creating a User using Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

### Explanation

I am wanting to set a user's security level when they register for an account. I don't want this to be a hidden field in the signup form as a person can then send in their own value to try and gain administrative privileges. So, it needs to be in the RegistrationController.

### Versions

Ruby: 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

Rails: 4.2.0

### Files

Here is what I have so far.

Added the following line to the `app/config/routes.rb` file:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations], 
           :controllers => { registrations: 'users/registrations' }

devise_scope :user do
    get    "login",             to: "devise/sessions#new",          as: :new_user_session
    post   "login",             to: "devise/sessions#create",       as: :user_session
    delete "logout",            to: "devise/sessions#destroy",      as: :destroy_user_session

    get    "register",           to: "devise/registrations#new",     as: :new_user_registration
    post   "register",           to: "devise/registrations#create",  as: :user_registration
    get    "account/delete",     to: "devise/registrations#cancel",  as: :cancel_user_registration

    get    "user/profile/edit",  to: "devise/registrations#edit",    as: :edit_user_registration

    patch  "user",              to: "devise/registrations#update"
    put    "user",              to: "devise/registrations#update"
    put    "register",          to: "devise/registrations#update"
    delete "user/delete",       to: "devise/registrations#destrony"

    get    "user/profile",      to: 'devise/registrations#edit',    as: :user_root
end
```

Here is my RegistrationController in the `app/controllers/users/registration_controller.rb` file:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController

    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, :only => [:create]

    def create
        super
          resource.update_attribute(:security_level, '1')
    end
end
```

My database does have a field called 'security_level' for all users.

Thank you in advance for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Do you want to set the security_level as one by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set `security_level = 1`, by default i would suggest you write it to the rails migration.

Code for migration

```
change_column_default :users, :security_level, '1'
```

If you want to do more by overriding the default devise crete function use the bellow code.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super do
        resource.security_level = '1'
        resource.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Since I already had the RegistrationsController created, I tried your second solution first as it would be faster to implement. That didn't seem to work for me.

I did try the first solution then for running a migration. That did the trick! 

Funny thing is, I had a similar issue in a past project and I did just that, I made the default for a column by doing a migration. For some reason I didn't even think of that solution here. Thank you @Coderhs for that solution and jarring my memory!

Answer (score 0):

You can face logic duplication problem in future (e.g. creating user from console will not force Rails to fill security level attribute, so you will need to control this in every place). Better to use callbacks in `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :set_security_level

  def set_security_level
    self.security_level = 1
  end
end
```

So, everytime User is going to be saved, `:set_security_level` will be executed.

Callbacks manual http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: When you mention, 'everytime User is going to be saved' do you mean even when the user updates their profile? In that case, this answer would not work. What if I change the user to being a higher security level (i.e. Basic User -> Moderator) and then they update their profile. They would revert back to a lower security level.

Comment: In this case you can use `after_create` callback.